# How to create indicator matrix from very large dataset in python

Tags: python, matrix, indicator, large-data

I'm running into confusingly large memory requirements for a relatively simple problem.

I have an ordered array of length N (index corresponds to sample ID) containing either an integer value or NaN.

I want to generate an indicator matrix of dimension N by N such that if two samples, *i* and *j*, both have a non-NaN value in the original list, then position *(i, j)* in the matrix is 1 and 0 otherwise (because the matrix is symmetrical I do not care about position *(j, i)*.

To pare back on memory requirements, I've implemented the following code, which instead of generating a square matrix creates an array that represents the condensed square matrix (ie what squareform would generate). But for an initial list of 66,000 entries, this script requires over 80GB of memory! I think this is failing because of the map line in *get_condensed_indeces*, but I don't know how to fix it. If anyone has any suggestions for reducing memory use please share!

Code below, should work with any input array.

```
def ind_matrix(x):
    ind = np.array([0.] * (len(x) * (len(x) - 1) / 2), dtype=np.float32)
    mask = np.where(~np.isnan(x))[0]
    targets = get_condensed_indeces(len(x), mask)
    ind[targets] += 1
    return ind

def get_condensed_indeces(n, desired_elements):
    # args:
    # n - number of cells in the current cluster
    # desired_elements - list of numpy indeces that specify
    # cells in a given cluster
    return map(
        index_converter,
        [[n, x[0], x[1]] for x in itertools.combinations(desired_elements, 2)]
    )

def index_converter(x):
    # mapping from position (i,j) in square matrix to index in squareform 1D array
    n, i, j = x[0], x[1], x[2]
    return n * i - (i * (i + 1)) / 2 + j - 1 - i
```

Comment: what do you mean it would take 80GB of memory? Is that how much you acctually have and it is taking up or is that calculated somehow, and if it is calculated how did you calculate it?

Comment: I submit the script as a batch job to LSF. The job fails with the following error message:


    TERM_MEMLIMIT: job killed after reaching LSF memory usage limit.
    Exited with exit code 143.

    Resource usage summary:

    CPU time   :   1295.30 sec.
    Max Memory :    101525 MB
    Max Swap   :    103220 MB

    Max Processes  :         3
    Max Threads    :         4

    The output (if any) is above this job summary.